# Efficient Algorithm to Find the Closest Integer Representation, in the Form $A\times\frac{N}{D}$ for a Value

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming, integers, numerical-algorithms, constraint-satisfaction

### The Problem

I am working on a problem that boils down to finding the closest representation of an arbitrary number ($x$) in the form:

$$x = A\times\frac{N}{D}$$

Where $A$ is a 32-bit integer, and $N$ and $D$ are 16-bit integers.

Typical inputs are real numbers between 1 and 1 billion.

---

### My Attempts

I first attempted to use $N$ and $D$ to represent the fractional part of the number, but I can only correct for errors less than one part in 65 thousand, not very useful.

I then looked at naively testing all the possible combinations of $N$ and $D$ to find one with the lowest remainder, even when skipping like fractions (i.e., 2/4, 3/6, etc.), and skipping values of $N$ that would result in a fraction that is too large ($N \leq \frac{x}{D}$). I still need to search more than a billion combinations.

Some test cases I have found challenging; clearly, it's pretty easy to come up with these.

- $1000\times \frac{255}{256}$
- $ 123456 \times \frac{123}{456}$

### Backround

This problem comes up as I am trying to configure a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) to convert arbitrary input frequencies to a uniform output frequency with the lowest error possible.

### Question

Is there a much more efficient way to solve this problem? Does this kind of problem have a name that I can look up?

Comment: How is the real number given as input in your problem? An input to an algorithm should be a finite string.

Comment: @Vincenzo Well, in my application, it would be a double-precision float. Here I use the term "Algorithm" in its colloquial sense. I also reviewed the tag description to see if this question was a good fit, "An algorithm is a sequence of well-defined steps that defines an abstract solution to a problem. Use this tag when your issue is related to design and analysis of algorithms". Based on that, I thought the tag was a good fit.

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm that is better (ideally substantially) than brute force for finding the optimal set of integers $A$, $N$, $D$ that gives the lowest error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, this problem is called [diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Approximation_of_a_rational_by_other_rationals).

However, your inputs are not just real numbers but double-precision floating point (aka `double`) numbers, which are in fact rational. Any `double` number has the [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

$$
(-1)^{sign} ( 1 . b_{51} b_{50} ... b_{0}) \times 2^{e - 1023}
$$
where $b$ encodes the mantissa (52 bits) and $e'=e-1023$ encodes the exponent (11 bits). You mention that your typical inputs are at least 1, so your exponent $e'$ is always nonnegative.
The mantissa is always an integer multiple of $2^{-52}$, and will be an integer multiple of $2^{-\ell}$ whenever the least significant nonzero bit of the mantissa is the $\ell$-th one.
The bottom line is that to achieve an *exact* representation you could do the following:

- look at the binary representation of your floating point number $x$, isolating the mantissa bit sequence $b$ and the exponent $e'=e-1023$;
- let $\ell$ be the index of the least significant nonzero bit of the mantissa $b$;
- your number $x$ is an integer multiple of $1/D = 2^{e' - \ell}$, *and no fraction with a smaller denominator than $D$ can represent it exactly*;
- divide $x$ by $1/D = 2^{e'-\ell}$ to find $N \times A$.

In the worst case, this may however not guarantee that $N$ and $A$ satisfy your size requirement, since $\ell- e'$ could be up to $52$, while you only have $32 + 16 = 48$ bits available for $N \times A$.
A practical solution (but perhaps non-optimal) would be to round the least significant $52-48 = 4$ bits in the mantissa of $x$.

If you insist on finding the best approximation given a constraint on the largest denominator $D$, we need to turn to diophantine approximation techniques and continued fractions.

A fraction $A/B$ is a *best rational approximation* to real number $x$ if $|A - Bx| \le |C - Dx|$ for all integers $C$ and $D$ where $0 < D \le B$.

Then [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Best_Diophantine_approximations_of_a_real_number) that the best rational approximation of $x$ is a so-called [*convergent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) to $x$, which you can recover from the continued fraction expansion of $x$:
$$
x = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \ldots}}
$$
The $m$-th convergent $C_m$ is defined by the fraction $A_m/B_m$ where $A_k$ and $B_k$ are defined recursively by

$A_{-1}=1$, $A_0=a_0$, $A_{k} = a_{k} A_{k-1} + A_{k-2}$

$B_{-1}=0$, $B_0=1$, $B_{k} = a_{k} B_{k-1} + B_{k-2}$.

In other words, for each $k=0,1,2,\ldots$:

- generate $a_k$ by setting $a_k = \lfloor x_k \rfloor$, $x_{k+1} = 1/(x_k - \lfloor x_k \rfloor)$, where $x_0 = x$;
- compute $A_k$ and $B_k$ with the formulas above
- the $k$-th convergent is $A_k/B_k$.

This will give you a sequence of closer and closer approximations of $x$, each of which is a best rational approximation. In your case, you want to stop when $B_k$ does not fit anymore into $16$ bits.

In your examples, we get the following:

First example.

$x = 1000 \times 255 / 256 \approx 996.09375$

$A_0 / B_0 = 996 / 1 \approx 996.0$

$A_1 / B_1 = 9961 / 10 \approx 996.1$

$A_2 / B_2 = 10957 / 11 \approx 996.0909090909091$

$A_3 / B_3 = 20918 / 21 \approx 996.0952380952381$

$A_4 / B_4 = 31875 / 32 \approx 996.09375$

Second example.

$x = 123456 \times 123 / 456 \approx 33300.63157894737$

$A_0 / B_0 = 33300 / 1 \approx 33300.0$

$A_1 / B_1 = 33301 / 1 \approx 33301.0$

$A_2 / B_2 = 66601 / 2 \approx 33300.5$

$A_3 / B_3 = 99902 / 3 \approx 33300.666666666664$

$A_4 / B_4 = 266405 / 8 \approx 33300.625$

$A_5 / B_5 = 632712 / 19 \approx 33300.63157894737$

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work well for my needs in practice. However, for around 0.08% of inputs, it does not find an optimal solution. For example, with the input $795082588 \times (1763/65225)$, the result is $988571985/46$, with an error of $1.5 \times 10^{-14}$. You can see my implementation [here](https://replit.com/@MarkOmo1/Real-to-Restricted-Fraction-Test?v=1).

Answer (score 1):

The "best" rational approximations to a real number are given by it's [continuous fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations), check that out.